# Anyway to connect more than one external monitor when using M1 MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-air

I connect two monitors with my M1 MacBook Air, but it failed.

> If your MacBook setup includes running more than one external display, you have a major problem. Apple's M1 or M2 chips won't allow it—at least natively.

As the topic mentioned, is there any way to solve it besides using the specific hub or dock?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406864/does-the-2020-apple-m1-macbook-pro-support-2x-daisy-chained-thunderbolt-displays

Answer (score 0):

### No.

#### There is no way past this built-in limit past buying a hub or dongle to do it.

As Apple clearly states in their official [MacBook Air (M1) specs](https://www.apple.com/macbook-air-m1/specs/):

> **Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display at millions of colors and**:
>
> One external display with up to 6K resolution at 60Hz
>
> **Thunderbolt 3 digital video output**
>
> Native DisplayPort output over USB-C
>
> VGA, HDMI, DVI, and Thunderbolt 2 output supported using adapters (sold separately)